# SQL Server BCP command query with where clause

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I had the BCP command working until I added the where clause. The use of the single quote around a char value is causing a syntax error. I have tried embedding triple single quotes and also tried using double quotes with success. Any ideas?

Use tmseprd

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000);

SELECT @sql =  'bcp "select studentid from tmseprd.dbo.Feith_Emas_Compare Where status = 'U' and counselor >199  and stage > 200 " queryout "C:\EMAS_Feith\advmove.txt" -c -t, -T  -S' + @@Servername;

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Comment: rather than double quote. Use two consecutive single quotes around the letter U in your select statement.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `''` and space after `-S`:

```
Select @sql = 'bcp "select studentid from tmseprd.dbo.Feith_Emas_Compare Where status = ''U'' and counselor >199  and stage > 200 " queryout "C:\EMAS_Feith\advmove.txt" -c -t, -T  -S ' + @@Servername;
```

Comment: Correct about using two single quotes, but I dont believe the space after the -S option has anything to do with it or that it is even going to fail without the space.